# Video.js changing source, but does not show new source

Tags: javascript, video.js

Sorry for my lack of knowledge on this topic

I have a script that changes the source of the video player. And it does just that. The only problem is that the Video.js player plays the first source assigned to it.

```
document.getElementById("vid-player_html5_api").innerHTML = "";

document.getElementById("vid-player_html5_api").innerHTML = "<source src='" + link + "' type='video/mp4'>";
document.getElementById("vid-player_html5_api").muted = false;
```

So if there were two buttons, and you clicked *Button 1* it would change the source of the player and show the correct video. Then lets say you clicked *Button 2* it would change the source of the player, **but it would still show the same video it showed for Button 1**

*It is proven that it changes the source, I checked the Chrome Dev tools and surely enough it changed the source*

## How do I fix this?

Comment: Put all your code to jsfiddle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try as below,

```js
function playVideo(videoSource, type) {
  var videoElm = document.getElementById('testVideo');
  var videoSourceElm = document.getElementById('testVideoSource'); 
   if (!videoElm.paused) {
        videoElm.pause();
     }
    
   videoSourceElm.src = videoSource;
   videoSourceElm.type = type;
  
    videoElm.load();
    videoElm.play();
  }
```

```html
<video id="testVideo" width="400" controls>
  <source id="testVideoSource">
</video>
<br/>
<input type="button" value="Play Video 1" onclick="playVideo('http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4', 'video/mp4')" />
<input type="button" value="Play Video 2" onclick="playVideo('http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.ogg', 'video/ogg')" />
```

Comment: I think the .load() does the trick. Is .load() a jQuery function or a built-in Video.js function

Comment: load is video built in function. I haven't used jquery above

Answer (score 14):

Just found this post the current pattern in VideoJS is to set .src with a JSON object for example

```
player.src({ type: 'video/mp4', src: new_url });
```

Comment: Worked perfectly

Answer (score 3):

The only way that worked with me is like that

```
var player = videojs(document.querySelector('.video-js'));
  player.src({
                src: 'videoURL,
                type: 'video/mp4'/*video type*/
            });

  player.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call video.js again once you've loaded the new video:

```
var current_vid = document.getElementById("vid-player_html5_api")
var next_vid = document.createElement('video');

next_vid.innerHTML = '<source src="' + link + '" type="video/mp4">';
next_vid.muted = false;

current_vid.parentNode.replaceChild( next_vid, current_vid );

videojs(current_vid, {}, function(){
  // do something when video.js is ready
});
```

[Video.js: dynamically loaded videos](http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/setup.html#alternative-setup-for-dynamically-loaded-html)

Answer (score 0):

For React
Dont return this in useEffect

```
 return() => {
        if(player){
            player.dispose()
        }
    }
```